# $M$ is an $R$-module with composition series. For any $R$-homomorphism $f: M\rightarrow M$, $M = \operatorname{Im}f^{n}\oplus\ker f^{n}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

**$M$ is an $R$-module with composition series. Show that for any $R$-homomorphism $f: M\rightarrow M$ there is a natural n such that $M = \operatorname{Im}f^{n}\oplus\ker f^{n}$.**

We know that $M$ has composition series, which means that $M$ is Artinian and Noetherian.
Now the kernel of any $R$ - module homomorphism is always a submodule, so we can consider the following ascending chain of kernels

$\ker f \subset \ker f^{2} \subset \ker f^{3} \subset \cdots \subset \ker f^{n} \subset \cdots$

that must eventually become constant by the Noetherian condition so we may suppose that there is a natural $n$ such that

$\ker f^{n} = \ker f^{n+1} = \ker f^{n+2}= \cdots $

I also thought to show that $\ker f^{n} \cap \operatorname{Im} f^{n} = \left \{ 0 \right \}$ so $M = \operatorname{Im}f^{n}\oplus \ker f^{n}$ from the definition of a vector space being the direct sum of two subspaces.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: We know that there exists an $n$ for which both $\ker f^k = \ker f^n$ and $\operatorname{im} f^k = \operatorname{im}f^n$ for all $k \geq n$. It follows that $f^n|_{\operatorname{im}f^n}$ is an isomorphism; otherwise, we would have $\ker f^{n} \subsetneq \ker f^{2n}$. That gives us $\ker f \cap \operatorname{im}f = \{0\}$. It then suffices to show that the submodule spanned by the image and kernel is all of $M$.